# Keeping Picasa and Photos on the same external hard drive. Will it work?

Tags: picasa

If I install Picasa on my External HD and keep all my photos on the same External HD, can I plug it in to any computer and keep all the Picasa albums, tags etc?

Comment: What have you researched so far? Have you read this - [Use Picasa on network or portable drives](https://sites.google.com/site/picasastartersite/)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to store databases of standalone photo organizers on external drives or network locations (no matter whether you use Picasa or other programs). Or if you decided to do this please make sure that the connection between your hard drive and computer is reliable. And don't unplug your HDD when Picasa has active background processes (importing, tags assignment, deleting photos, etc...) cause it might lead to the database corruption.